# Converted JavaScript to Java, still persisting errors

Tags: java, javascript

I have made an algorithm in JavaScript and am trying to convert it to Java. I don't have too much experience with Java and am getting errors when trying to compile this code and I don't know exactly what is wrong with the syntax. I've done some research but perhaps there is something I am missing with the function calling, the recursive processes. And yes I have to return the number as a string.

```
public class Answer {
    public static String answer(int l, int r, int n) { 

        int acc = 0;

        for (int k=1; k<=n; k++) {
            acc += comb(n-1, k-1) * f(k-1, l-1) * f(n-k, r-1);
        }
        return acc;

    }

    public static int f(int n, int l) {
        if (n==l) {
            return 1;
        }  else if (n<l) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            int acc = 0;
            for (int k=1; k<=n; k++) {
                acc += comb(n-1, k-1) * f(k-1, l-1) * fact(n-k);
            }
            return acc;
        }

    }


    public static int comb(int n, int k){
        return fact(n) / (fact(k) * fact(n-k));
    }


    public static int fact(int n) {
        int acc = 1;
        for (int i=2; i<=n; i++) {
            acc *= i;
        }
        return acc;
    }

}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: /Answer.java:52: error: class, interface, or enum expected } ^

Comment: I also get a return type error among others because it is returning a number and I'm trying to get it to return a string

Comment: There aren't even 52 lines of code in the sample you've posted above… what line is the error pointing to?

Comment: @Paul_R: You cannot cast an `int` to a `String`. Maybe `String.valueOf(acc)`.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard It was pointing to the very last `}`, I just got rid of some extraneous blank lines in my question

Comment: That first one probably just means you have more `}` characters than `{` characters.  Check how you've nested them.  And re the second error - take Thilo's advice, not Paul_R's.

Comment: How are you calling this code? Do you have a class with a `main` method?

Comment: If I provided all the JavaScript code would someone be able to give me a working Java file?

Answer (score 0):

Compiled almost fine with: javac Answer.java

but the error code says:

```
Answer.java:9: error: incompatible types
        return acc;
               ^
  required: String
  found:    int
```

Indicating that in line 9 we have returned an int, when the function specifies a String as a return type.

Depending of what you want, there are 2 possible solutions, changing your function to either of :

```
public static int answer(int l, int r, int n) { 

    int acc = 0;

    for (int k=1; k<=n; k++) {
        acc += comb(n-1, k-1) * f(k-1, l-1) * f(n-k, r-1);
    }
    return acc;

}
```

or

```
public static String answer(int l, int r, int n) { 

    int acc = 0;

    for (int k=1; k<=n; k++) {
        acc += comb(n-1, k-1) * f(k-1, l-1) * f(n-k, r-1);
    }
    return String.valueOf(acc);

}
```